# compare data from current day with previous month

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a huge table (in Hadoop) partitioned by day.

From that table, I would like to create an anomaly table that will compare the locations of **each day** with the locations of the **previous month**.

If a location in the current **day** wasn't in the previous **month** it will add it in the anomaly table.

- I don't want to do it in code but only in SQL.

I know it should be possible in standard databases,

the question is:
Is it possible in **Hadoop** and what will be the best way?

Thx

Comment: If you're using Hive then you just need to join the table to itself on `current_day=same_day_last_month` and go from there.

Comment: I want to compare month with day

Comment: OK so the exact join criteria changes slightly but hopefully you get the idea?

Comment: I think I do. It looks like standard SQL. Is it a recommended way?